# How to use poisson to predict incidence rates per 100,000?

Tags: r, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, epidemiology

I am trying to make predictions with a poission model to get the predicted incidence rate per 100,000 of some event. My problem is that when I compare the predicted incidence to the incidence calculated manually they are very different.

```
counts <- sort(round(rnorm(n=500,mean = 200, sd = 15),0))
group <- sort(round(runif(500, min = 1, max = 5),0)).   # data is stratified by groups
denom <- sort(round(rnorm(n=500,mean = 200000, sd = 15000),0))
IRper100000 <- (counts/denom)*100000

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(counts,denom,group,IRper100000))

fit <- glm(counts ~ group + offset(log(denom/10000)),family=quasipoisson,data=df)

df$preds <- predict(fit,df)     # check predictions on original dataset
head(df)


counts  denom  group IRper100000    preds
161     153211 1     105.08384      5.023637
161     161488 1     99.69781       5.076252
162     161543 1     100.28290      5.076593
163     164915 1     98.83880       5.097252
165     164942 1     100.03516      5.097415
166     165728 1     100.16412      5.102169
```

I was expecting the `preds` column to be in the same ball park as `CIRRper100000` but you can see they don't look comparable. I have cleary misunderstood something in the poison model, possibly use of the offset. Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: What is `CIRRper100000`? Is it the same as `IRper100000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the theoretical aspect. You are using a Poisson regression to predict count, not IRper100000. So although there is a direct relation between counts and IRper100000, we need to transform the count predictions into IRper100000 predictions. After finding the predicted counts, you can multiple by `100000/denom` to get the predicted IRper100000

Second, you need to specify `type = "response"` in your predict call. By default it gives the fitted predictions on the linear scale. In this model the link function is the log link, whose inverse is the exponential. Taking the exponential of your predictions matches the `type = "response"` method. See `?predict.glm` for more details.

(Also, you multiple by 100000 to get IRper100000. But in your offset you only divide by 10000. That actually doesn't matter as it just changes the intercept by a flat amount, but it could still be confusing. Assuming it's just a typo, your use of the offset looks correct to me.)

```r
set.seed(2022)
counts <- sort(round(rnorm(n=500,mean = 200, sd = 15),0))
group <- sort(round(runif(500, min = 1, max = 5),0))
denom <- sort(round(rnorm(n=500,mean = 200000, sd = 15000),0))
IRper100000 <- (counts/denom)*100000
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(counts,denom,group,IRper100000))
fit <- glm(counts ~ group + offset(log(denom/100000)),family=quasipoisson,data=df)

# Note that taking exp() of the linear predictions gives the count predictions
df$preds_linear <- predict(fit, df)
df$preds_manual <- exp(predict(fit, df))
df$preds_response <- predict(fit, df, type = "response")
# Transform the predicted counts into rates
df$preds_IR <- (df$preds_response/df$denom)*100000
head(df)
#>   counts  denom group IRper100000 preds_linear preds_manual preds_response
#> 1    148 158591     1    93.32182     5.058078     157.2880       157.2880
#> 2    154 163750     1    94.04580     5.090091     162.4046       162.4046
#> 3    156 164444     1    94.86512     5.094320     163.0929       163.0929
#> 4    163 166250     1    98.04511     5.105242     164.8840       164.8840
#> 5    167 167455     1    99.72829     5.112464     166.0791       166.0791
#> 6    167 167585     1    99.65092     5.113240     166.2081       166.2081
#>   preds_IR
#> 1 99.17837
#> 2 99.17837
#> 3 99.17837
#> 4 99.17837
#> 5 99.17837
#> 6 99.17837
# The mean predicted counts matches the observed
mean(df$counts)
#> [1] 199.49
mean(df$preds_response)
#> [1] 199.49
# As does the mean predicted incidence rate
mean(df$IRper100000)
#> [1] 99.14174
mean(df$preds_IR)
#> [1] 99.14738
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Finally, note that in this model the predicted incidence rate is the same within each group, as we would expect.

Comment: excellent thank you!